# clearInterval with start and stop buttons

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a simple countdown using `setinterval` and I get the error that my functions are not defined. I am using the buttons to start and stop the intervals. Any ideas why this happens?

**Javascript**

```
function startCount() {
    $(function() {
        var count = 10;
        countdown = setInterval(function() {
            $("p.countdown").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
            if (count === 0) {
                window.location = 'http://google.com';
            }
            count--;
        }, 1000);
    });
}



function startStop() {
    clearInterval(countdown);
}​
```

**html**

```
<p class="countdown"></p>
<button onclick="startCount()">Start</button>
<button onclick="startStop()">Stop</button>
```

**demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/54uQz/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your *countdown* variable outside the `startCount()` function so that it is visible to both functions. At the moment it only exists in the first, so clearing the timer does nothing.

**CODE:**

```
var countdown;

function startCount() {
    var count = 10;
    countdown = setInterval(function() {
        $("p.countdown").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
        if (count === 0) {
            window.location = 'http://google.com';
        }
        count--;
    }, 1000);
}


function startStop() {
    clearInterval(countdown);
}
```

The Updated [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/54uQz/8/)

Comment: thank you works great. Just one problem when I click the start button more than once the countdown increases rapidly. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Call `startStop();` before `var count = 10;` See [this Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/54uQz/9/)